# Cakephp routing only for frontend pages without a prefix

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am working on site

http://solarsmart.com.pk/

and I have created a controller and action for pages which gets all the pages data from database on the basis of last two values from the following url

http://solarsmart.com.pk/pages/page/about/about-us

I want to remove `/pages/page` which are controller and action respectively. if I set the route as follows

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'page','manager'=>FALSE));
```

It works but then the problem arises that the admin routing pages also redirect to `pages/page` I want them to remain as they are right now

Comment: You need to provide all your routes. Alternatively, all your page names.

Comment: I want this url 
http://solarsmart.com.pk/pages/page/about/about-us
to be like
http://solarsmart.com.pk/about/about-us
but the urls with manager prefix to remain as it is 
http://solarsmart.com.pk/manager/posts/add

but there can be unknown number of pages

Comment: If you've only got one page write one specific route. If you have multiple pages - please reread my previous comment and edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and what I did following
I got the url from the Router Class like

```
$curUrl = Router::url();// returns the current url of the page
$curUrl = explode('/', $curUrl); // exploding on the base of '/'
```

then I checked that if the url has the required prefix or not 
which in your case will be like the following

```
if (!in_array('admin', $curUrl)) {
    Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'page', 'admin' => FALSE));
}
```

Comment: it causes inconsistency with internal cake urls. (plugins and etc)